# How to display a column of values next to an offset by one position without using lag

Tags: sql, subquery, window-functions

Have

```
id | value
-----------
1   | 2
1   | 3
1   | 45
```

Need

```
id | value | value2
------------------------
1 | 2 | ---
1 | 3 | 2
1 | 45 | 3
--|---- | 45
```

Could you show variant, how to achive this?

Comment: And why don't you want to use lag()?  Tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You do want `lag()`:

```
select id, value,
    lag(value) over(partition by id order by value) value1
from mytable
```

In databases that do not support window functions, an alternative is a subquery:

```
select id, value,
    (select max(value) from mytable t1 where t1.id = t.id and t1.value < t.value) value1
from mytable t
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is to use `lag()`:

```
select id, value, lag(value) over (order by value) as prev_value
from t;
```

In a database that doesn't support `lag()`, you can use a correlated subquery.  Something like:

```
select t.*,
       (select t2.value
        from t t2
        where t2.value < t.value
        order by t2.value desc
        fetch first 1 row only
       ) as prev_value
from t;
```

Not all databases support the standard `fetch first`, but all should have something similar.